# how to get the name of this shooting technique?

Tags: light-painting

I really wonder :  how this photo was taken ?
what is the name of such of these technique ? 
how I can take such of these photographs ?

could you please teach me :)

[image]

Comment: Please see [this article on how to ask "what is this effect" questions effectively](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called "[light painting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_painting)" and you will find many examples of it on the web. You need a long exposure and a source of light (a light stick, a flashlight, a cigarette even). You put your camera on a tripod, release the shutter, and then start moving your light source to "paint" whatever it is you want to get. You can release a flash in the meanwhile to get a still of yourself doing the actual painting.

Comment: cigarette ? I doubt !

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/groups/photomaniaque/discuss/72157610185140488/

Comment: Cameras record light; cigarettes emit light.  How is there room for doubt?